# How can I trigger macOS system gamepad API based on a value received from iOS app through core bluetooth

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, uikit, core-bluetooth

I'm building a macOS and iOS app in which the iOS app sends commands by updating the characteristics value based on GCVirtualController. The commands will be received by the macOS app via core bluetooth. After receiving the command I need to call the OS game pad apis so that when ever a button is pressed on iOS device the macOS app will receive it and register it as a button press from a gamepad which can be used in other macOS apps and games which supports gamepad. Is there any way to access the OS gamepad API in cocoa